# Pivot groups of row data into columns using Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I've got data I'm reading in as a dataframe from a CSV using Pandas (in Python). The CSV looks basically like the following:

```
image    img1.jpg
date     Thursday, May 5
link     bit.ly/asdf
subject  'Unique subject line 1'
image    img2.jpg
date     Tuesday, May 17
link     bit.ly/zxcv
subject  'Unique subject line 2'
image    img3.jpg
date     Monday, May 9
link     bit.ly/sdfg
subject  'Unique subject line 3'
```

I'd like to get it into a dataframe where each unique grouping is in a single row, with the attributes that are currently listed as row data in column 1 as column names. So something like the following:

```
image      date                 link           subject
img1.jpg   Thursday, May 5      bit.ly/asdf    'Unique subject line 1'
img2.jpg   Tuesday, May 17      bit.ly/zxcv    'Unique subject line 2'
img3.jpg   Monday, May 9        bit.ly/sdfg    'Unique subject line 3'
```

I've tried using `pandas.pivot_table` and also just creating an empty dataframe with the columns I want, but with both methods, I'm having trouble with either indexing or aggregating. I think this is because I'm not grouping by any one attribute, and I'm not trying to aggregate any numeric data.

It seems like it should be simple enough to reshape the data in this way, but I'm not sure how to define the groupings I want. Is there a way to do this using `pivot_table`, or would it be best to do it another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, as the data currently is formatted, there isn't a unique way to group the images during a pivot.  Any date could be grouped with `img1.jpg` during a pivot, as there isn't any additional data saying which date should correspond to each image.

To fix this, we just need to add an additional column with the grouping information.  Judging by your output, the grouping essentially go in row order; the first 4 rows go together, the next 4 rows go together, etc.  To enumerate repeats like this, [`numpy.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) is useful, you just need to know the number of images and attributes.  Some basic math allows us to get the number of images and number of attributes in general:

```
# Add an grouping column.
nbr_images = (df['col1'] == 'image').sum()
nbr_attributes = len(df)/nbr_images
df['image_group'] = np.repeat(range(nbr_images), nbr_attributes)
```

Now, it's straightforward to pivot:

```
# Pivot the DataFrame.
pivoted_df = df.pivot(columns='col1', index='image_group', values='col2')

# Clear the index and column name.
pivoted_df.index.name = None
pivoted_df.columns.name = None
```

The resulting output:

```
              date     image         link                subject
0  Thursday, May 5  img1.jpg  bit.ly/asdf  Unique subject line 1
1  Tuesday, May 17  img2.jpg  bit.ly/zxcv  Unique subject line 2
2    Monday, May 9  img3.jpg  bit.ly/sdfg  Unique subject line 3
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! For anyone else with similarly-structured data, I needed to use df.pivot(columns=0, values=1, index='image_group') OR add names to the columns passed in to pivot for the columns and values arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use[`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for creating `image_group` and then [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
df['image_group'] = (df.col1 == 'image').cumsum() - 1
print df.pivot(columns='col1', index='image_group', values='col2')
        .rename_axis(None)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)

              date     image         link                  subject
0  Thursday, May 5  img1.jpg  bit.ly/asdf  'Unique subject line 1'
1  Tuesday, May 17  img2.jpg  bit.ly/zxcv  'Unique subject line 2'
2    Monday, May 9  img3.jpg  bit.ly/sdfg   'Uniquesubject line 3'
```

Alternatively you can use one line:

```
print pd.pivot(columns=df['col1'], 
               index=(df.col1 == 'image').cumsum() - 1, 
               values=df['col2'])
        .rename_axis(None)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)

              date     image         link                  subject
0  Thursday, May 5  img1.jpg  bit.ly/asdf  'Unique subject line 1'
1  Tuesday, May 17  img2.jpg  bit.ly/zxcv  'Unique subject line 2'
2    Monday, May 9  img3.jpg  bit.ly/sdfg   'Uniquesubject line 3'
```

EDIT: If columns of original DataFrame are `0` and `1` use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for selecting:

```
print pd.pivot(columns=df.iloc[:,0], 
               index=(df.iloc[:,0] == 'image').cumsum() - 1, 
               values=df.iloc[:,1])
        .rename_axis(None)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)

              date     image         link                  subject
0  Thursday, May 5  img1.jpg  bit.ly/asdf  'Unique subject line 1'
1  Tuesday, May 17  img2.jpg  bit.ly/zxcv  'Unique subject line 2'
2    Monday, May 9  img3.jpg  bit.ly/sdfg   'Uniquesubject line 3'
```